Selection of reasonable Power and Alpha for Sample Size calculation
I'm performing an A-B test which involves response rates to communications sent out to customers. I'm looking to calculate a required sample size, and I don't know the expected response rate of the challenger -- and it actually may be the same as the champion and this would be a valid outcome. So it looks like I'll be using a "Minimum Detectable Effect" approach.
I'm pretty happy with this, and I know (think?) that some reasonable default values are power = 0.8 and alpha = 0.05.
Given the nature of the experiment, are they reasonable values to use? If so I'm happy to put together a table of "Sample Size vs Minimum Detectable Effect" and run it past the stake holders to discuss.
For reference, I'm using the pwr library in R:
sample_size <- pwr.2p.test(h = h, sig.level = alpha, power = power, alternative = "two.sided")

Additionally, it looks to me like a Z-Test would be the appropriate way to asses the experiment, is that correct?

These are typically the choices left to the domain expert, not the statistician: Are you comfortable with an $\alpha = 5%$ chance of concluding a difference between A and B, even though there is none? What about a $1 - \beta = 20%$ chance of not detecting a significant difference with your sample size, even though there is a difference between A and B? These are the error rate you choose when setting the power and alpha levels.

What @FransRodenburg said. Also, I have learnt to rephrase: 95% confidence sounds better than “a 1 in 20 chance of drawing the incorrect conclusion”. It IS a ‘standard’ choice, but not a particularly ambitious choice. 80% power rephrases to ‘1 in 5 chance of failing to detect the effect if it really is there’.
For preliminary investigation these values are often just fine. But I keep telling my boss these levels are nowhere near ambitious enough to support multi-million euro investment decisions, so that’s why I want all those follow-up investigations.

The appropriateness of a Z-test will depend a lot on your sample size and proportions; for smaller samples and for proportions close to the boundaries (0 or 1) better alternatives exist.

I'd say the way to think about this is to consider a) Which type of error is worse and b_ How much a priori knowledge you have.

Thanks all, that's all very useful info and ways of thinking about it. I'll have a ponder over the weekend and a chat with my colleagues next week.
